# Forms authentication after a user session has expired

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication

I have an asp Login control in a jQueryUI dialog box that is hidden until a user's session is near or has already passed expiration. I'm reading a custom field in the aspxauth cookie from client script to display an "extend your session" message, which if the user clicks, sends an async XHR to the server which returns cookies with updated values. All of this is working fine. My problem comes when a user does not respond to the "extend session" message and their session expires. They then see the jQuery dialog with the Login control which should allow them to authenticate without taking them to the default login page. When a user submits their credentials via the login control is takes them to the default login page and does not authenticate them. What do?

- I am not using ASP.NET AJAX
- I have implemented the FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate event in the Global.asax, so I do have access to the FormsAuthenticationEventArgs object there if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend the FormsAuthentication timeout at the same time you extend the session.

Here is something I use

```
    public void Extend(int SessionLimit)
    {
        FormsAuthenticationTicket OriginalTicket = ((FormsIdentity)Context.User.Identity).Ticket;
        FormsAuthenticationTicket NewTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, OriginalTicket.Name, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(SessionLimit), false, OriginalTicket.UserData);
        HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(NewTicket));
        authCookie.HttpOnly = true;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
    }
```

Comment: I'm going to mark this one as the answer because it did resolve another issue I was having implementing this feature, which is returning a new aspxauth cookie in an async XHR request.

Comment: However, in my original question I was trying to deal with a user whose session had already expired and thus had to authenticate again, but doing so without being redirected to the default login page. I ended up throwing in the towel here and simply sending the expired user to our home page with an appended query string that told the script to throw the login dialog box and display a session timeout message.

Comment: I have not been able to find away to avoid going to the login page if the session/forms times out, even if I catch it before the redirect.  So this is what I did because I too threw in the towel :)

Answer (score 0):

We don't have exactly the same setup as you do and I am not exactly sure how your re-authentication works, so I could be off base, but we had a very similar issue.

The problem that we had was that the page that we used for login re-authentication was under authentication control (i.e. to get to it, you had to be logged in).

The solution was to add an entry to web.config to "unprotect" that page. For example, we added the following to the main configuration element:

```
  <location path="loginreauth.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Once we did this, everything worked correctly.